# UIImageView's image dont change by code

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage

I know that my problem is stupid but i'm not able to fix it and i didn't find any answer.
I have an IBoutlet UIImageView in a Custom UITableViewCell. I set it's UIImage in IB and i want to change it by code when the custom cell is taped.
My code is as follow. But somehow image is not changing.
This is a method from my custom UItableViewCell.

```
-(void)setExpanded:(BOOL)expand
{
    if(expand)
    {
        [self.expandedImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bt_up.png"]];
        expanded = YES;
        //self.infoLabel.hidden = NO;
        //[self setNeedsDisplay];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.expandedImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bt_down.png"]];
        expanded = NO;
        //self.infoLabel.hidden = YES;
        //[self setNeedsDisplay];
    }

}
```

I tried to play with "SetNeedDisplay". I also tried to change the UIimage outside of the CustomCell but dont works.

Any help will be very appreciated because i'm on it since so much time ;)

regards,

Comment: Can you check to see if the imageNamed: message is returning a null pointer?

Comment: who is "self"? is expandedImageView retained and visible in "self"?

Comment: i checked for a nil pointer but imagedNamed return a valid pointer. self is the custom UITableViewCell and expandedImage is totaly visible in self. expandedImage is an IBOutlet UIImageView.

Answer (score 0):

There could be 2 possible reasons:

1. Your self.expandedImageView is nil
2. You don't have images named bt_up.png, bt_down.png

Comment: self.expandedImageView is a valid pointer and i have those image. It's very strange. But thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If your image and properties really are valid, then I'd suggest checking which thread is calling `setExpanded:`. Cocoa states that UI objects should only be modified by the UI thread, so if you're invoking it from some timer or BG thread then maybe that's the issue.

Comment: I dont have second thread or timer taht invoke setExpanded. It's very very strange. I really dont know where can be the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Try printing its (custom UITableViewCell) subviews and check if the image instance exists or not in the list, if exists try changing image for that instance.